# Best Redis setup for session caching

Tags: redis

I see there are multiple modes of operation for Redis (cluster, sentinel, master-slave, etc?).  I don't fully understand the implications of each, but my question is this:

If I have a web application that requires distributed session persistence, which configuration of Redis makes the most sense?  The main reason I'm using redis is to achieve some level of fault tolerance.  If one of my frontend servers fails, I want the sessions to be available for other nodes to pickup the workload.  If a redis node goes down, I don't want this to affect the user experiences, and I don't want to have to wake up a developer at midnight to correct the matter.

Answer (score 0):

From everything I've read, Redis Sentinel is the way to go for fault tolerance.